# Razor Class Library for Blazor Hybrid app in .Net8 Fails with No Registered service of type Routing.IScrollToLocationHash at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Co

Tags: c#, .net, razor-class-library, blazor-hybrid

Out of the boks I'm createing a Blazor Hybrid App with a Razor Class library using .Net 8

1. Includes a project reference to the RCL
2. Moving the folders Pages, Shared and Data to the Class Library.
3. Correcting the namespace and Using's where needed.
4. Adding an addisjonal assembly to the Main.Razor file in the main
   hybrid project

When running the program I get the following error:

> s:1  Cannot provide a value for property 'ScrollToLocationHash' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.IScrollToLocationHash'.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateComponent(Type componentType)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree, Dictionary`2 namedEventIndexes)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
> NotifyUnhandledException @ blaz

With .NET 7 This works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, add this to your csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView" Version="8.0.0" />
```